# How to reset input field in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm Try to reset input field when user submit thire item. But I don't figure it out. Here is my code.

```js
const onSubmit = (myData) => {
    const url = "https://automobilereact.herokuapp.com/product";
    const newData = { ...myData, sold: 0 };
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newData),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => console.log(result));

    const { data } = axios.post("https://automobilereact.herokuapp.com/add-item", {
      ...myData,
      email: user.email,
      sold: 0,
    });
  };
```

Comment: where's the code for the input?

Comment: Are you storing the input value(s) in state?

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple solutions but this is the best way to do it

bind the input to a state:

```js
const [inputContent, setInputContent] = useState("Default value")
```

code for input:

```js
<input onChange={(e) => setInputContent(e.target.value)} value={inputContent} />
```

On submit remove the `inputContent` value

```js
const onSubmit = (myData) => {
  setInputContent("")
  // Rest of code...
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const onSubmit = (myData) => {
    const url = "https://automobilereact.herokuapp.com/product";
    const newData = { ...myData, sold: 0 };
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newData),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => console.log(result));

    const { data } = axios.post("https://automobilereact.herokuapp.com/add-item", {
      ...myData,
      email: user.email,
      sold: 0,
    });

 // Try this out....
 let inputs = document.getElementById("id");
 inputs.value = "";
  };
```

Use this method for every input field. Just Set their value to empty. Like this...

```
let inputs = document.getElementById("id");
 inputs.value = "";
  };
```

Remember use all of them at the last of post method. If you use it before posting the value your data will be sent empty.